# What exactly went wrong with my answer here?

Tags: discussion

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/33843/19097

This one got *4 downvotes*. I'm very, *very* puzzled.

It seems to me like a perfectly **reasonable** and **clearly worded** answer:

"**No**, it's not too late, **yes**, you need a teacher, **neither** instrument is easy".

Each of these points is, in my opinion, clearly justified.

Okay, so it also includes a sarcastic stab at Michael Nyman/Philip Glass and easy listening piano, but I have seen people get away with worse attempts at humour.

What's so **wrong** with it?
How is that a *wrong* answer, a *bad* answer?

I am extremely suspicious that it is a matter of people simply *thinking otherwise* - this genuinely *surprises me*, as it seems to me that there couldn't be 4 people in the world insane enough to think that 26 years old is too late to start learning *or* insane enough to think that if you start learning from scratch at 26 a teacher is useless since you've-got-oh-so-much-time-to-waste.

I strongly feel about this not because oh-my-God-I'm-gonna-lose-reputation (if I gave a shit about reputation I could simply find 3 or 4 posts with crappy grammar or spelling to edit and regain the points pronto), but because I feel like **OP might be damaged by all of this** (as in, "I read a bunch of single-digit-rep users on SE saying that a teacher is useless and piano is much easier than violin, the only guy who didn't agree was downvoted into the depths of hell, now I've got RSI and I can't play anyway - what did I do wrong?").

Comment: Actually I decided I give enough shits that I am deleting the post. It's not *me* that's getting RSI after all. I still don't understand the *problem*, though, and it has to be something obvious.

Comment: +1 "don't get mad, get *meta*"

Comment: there are a lot of emphasized words. I have some problem reading this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the reason why it was so heavily downvoted (which shows up on my phone, but not my computer):

[image]

It doesn't look like spam, so I'm guessing it was marked as offensive and it didn't take too much digging for figuring out why:

> The piano is easier to fake, though.
>
> There is some easy-ish repertory which sounds almost listenable to
>   untrained ears and/or women you may be trying to seduce, Michael Nyman
>   and all that, which is easily doable with 2 years of practice.
>
> It's also a crime against humanity, but you are not a man of moral
>   scruples, are you.

I can see this being perceived as offensive by some people, and to be honest is completely and utterly unnecessary in your answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did not see that - could that possibly be because you have a ginormous reputation score? Yes, I can see people being offended too, sure. I completely disagree about that bit being **unnecessary**, though, it's in my opinion the *main* difference between piano and violin: luckily there is **no The Heart Asks Pleasure First or Amelie's Theme for violin**. It could certainly have been worded differently if I did care about the feeling of humourless people or Nyman fans (turns out I don't, nor do I care about OP's future frustration and RSI).

Comment: @SomeDudeOnTheInterwebs you don't think that they are correlated  at all?  There have been less offensive posts that have been down voted for the same reason.

Comment: I already answered your question in the comment that was deleted. TL;DR: it's not my problem, that was the only **RIGHT** answer and this should come first, I don't have the time to cater to the taste of humorless strangers on the internet, okthxbye.

Comment: @SomeDudeOnTheInterwebs: The difference between humour and snobbery is not crystal clear in the case of the quote from your text. What I like with SE is that hyperbole isn't such a big thing as in the rest of the internet. Also, given a diligent practice regimen and two years, most people should for sure be able to learn the piano good enough so even trained ears would not recoil in horror... You seem to believe that anyone attempting an instrument is aiming for total mastery and a place in the symphony orchestra, while there is nothing in the questions even hinting at this.