# information and reason for a downvote

Tags: support

Is there a place on the site that explains why and for what reason someone gives a downvote ?

I got a minus one on a question that I asked. I was thinking the rationale behind  giving an up or down is to learn to formulate, and ask better questions. So if someone  gives a downvote they should explain themselves to learn from them to ask better questions.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, it is good to leave a comment explaining why a user is downvoting a post, but it's not obligatory. People all over the SE sites downvote without explaining. Unless the user has left a comment, you cannot see why or who downvoted you.

When you see a downvote on a post of yours without any given reason, read the post again and see if you can improve anything that might have caused a user to downvote. If you cannot find anything wrong with it, don't take it so hard, all of us get downvoted for no reason.

Comment: I just want to bold this: "**all of us get downvoted**". It reminds me of a maxim of sorts: "Sometimes the opinion someone has of you says more about them than it does about you". Some people are going to downvote for reasons that would never make sense to us, but it all works out in the end because the reasonable upvoters outnumber the irrational downvotes, and the irrational downvotes seem to be spread evenly across all posts, given enough time.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on every meta many, many times in the meta [like this quesiton for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

While feedback is nice, there are problems with this idea in general and the most damming problem in my mind is if down votes require an comment, then why should people be allowed to up vote without comment? Misplaced up votes can be just as bad and in general people don't always vote up or down for the right reasons. Also people are people and while a vote is suppose to be for the content, some users take it personal so putting a user with every down vote won't help [for example this other meta post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/what-exactly-went-wrong-with-my-answer-here).

If it's rep you are worrying about, it's kind of irrelevant. You'll get a -2 for every down vote, but +5 for an up voted question and +10 for an up voted answer so the rep distribution already favors up votes.

Comment: The other side of the rep coin is that if you are actually negative rep for a question or answer then there is *probably* a legitimate issue with it, unless it's a negative rep from a single downvote and no one else has really looked at it. Once you have -2 votes on something with more than 20 views or so, it's definitely time to think there's a problem. If you're 0 on something because you have two downs and two ups, then you're net positive rep with a possibly controversial answer.

Comment: Also you must not take downvotes lightly as the downvoter.  Because it costs -2 reputation to cast a downvote.  I suppose that discourages revenge downvoting just because someone's ego was bruised.

Comment: @RockinCowboy It only costs 1 rep. The person who gets down voted get -2.

Comment: @Dom - Oh okay - thanks for the clarification.  I knew it cost something to cast a downvote.  Never paid much attention to the exact number.